# Authenticate with Flask-LDAP3-Login based on group membership

Tags: python, authentication, flask, ldap, ldap3

I'm new to Flask and I'm trying out Flask-LDAP3-Login.

I've followed the documentation here and i have it working which is great: https://flask-ldap3-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

How would i go about authenticating a user based on whether they are a member of a specific group? I see the docs mention group filtering but i'm not sure how to put it all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is curious, i solved this myself doing the following:

First, i integrated flask-ldap3-login with Flask-SQLAlchemy using steps here - https://github.com/nickw444/flask-ldap3-login/issues/26

My save user method now looks like this:

```
@ldap_manager.save_user
def save_user(dn, username, data, memberships):
    id=int(data.get("uidNumber"))
    if 'group-goes-here' in data.get("memberOf"):
        user=User.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        if not user:
            user=User(
                id=int(id),
                dn=dn,
                username=username,
                email=data['mail'],
                firstname=data['givenName'],
                lastname=data['sn']
            )
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

        return user
```

So basically provided the user enters valid LDAP credentials it goes to AD to retrieve their group memberships and its a simple if 'group-goes-here' in data.get("memberOf"): determines whether to save the user in my User model and return it back to the handler.

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Redirect users who are not logged in.
    form = LDAPLoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.user:
            login_user(form.user)
        else:
            flash('Login Failed', 'warning')
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `LDAP_USER_OBJECT_FILTER` can be used to check group membership. If a user is not found within the group, an authentication fail will be produced. This is taken from the [flask-ldap3-login docs](https://flask-ldap3-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#filters-searching):

> Specifies what object filter to apply when searching for users. Defaults to '(objectclass=person)'

---

Matching **direct members** of a group:

```
app.config['LDAP_USER_OBJECT_FILTER'] = '(objectclass=person)(memberOf=<DN of Group>)'
```

---

For **nested group membership** you can use `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN`:

```
app.config['LDAP_USER_OBJECT_FILTER'] = '(objectclass=person)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=<DN of Group>)'
```

The [Microsoft Search Filter Syntax docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax#operators) state:

> This is a special "extended" match operator that walks the chain of ancestry in objects all the way to the root until it finds a match.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a ldap server ? if not go to https://www.openldap.org/ and follow instructions on how to install openldap server
 if you prefer a  docker container then go here
https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap  and follow steps to  get the container up and running 
then go here https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/tutorial.html

pip install ldap3 on the machine which has your python env or another python container (same bridge network as your ldap container)

open python console and type the following commands

```
>>> from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
>>> server = Server('ipa.demo1.freeipa.org')
>>> conn = Connection(server)
>>> conn.bind()
True
```

first with this free ldap server ipa.demo1.freeipa.org
 and then with your own ldap server ip address

Comment: Hi there thanks for your reply. Yes i'm using my company's AD in order to authenticate. I'm familiar with ldap3 as i use it for another project of mine however Flask-LDAP3-Login seems useful as it integrates with Flask-Login.

Comment: A user can be in more than one ou its either a valid or not a valid user  what is the use case ?

Comment: No I think you’re confused a user can only be in one OU. What I need to do is validate based on whether the user is a member of a certain group. Thanks for your suggestion but it’s not really answering my question.