# Is form/login still required when using FlaskLDAP3Login for Single Sign-On purpose?

Tags: python, flask, ldap, single-sign-on

Simply saying, I am developing an app using Flask. For this app I am trying to implement a Single Sign-On, so a user never needs to enter credentials, e.g. *username* and *password*.

The authentication and authorization in this case will go through Kerberos together with LDAPS. The Kerberos part is not done yet, however, Kerberos is intended to get a "username" via a middleware currently logged into a system (Windows), when requesting an app's link. Afterwards this variable i.e. "username" will be proceeded with LDAPS, to check whether a user belongs to Active Directory or not. If yes - provide access and permission to a web site, if no - forbid.

However, since my user wont type anything, I do not understand whether I need to use either the Flask Form (flask-wtf) or the Flask Login (flask-login e.g. `UserMixin`) as well as how shall I provide an access to my user?

I was able to set up the FlaskLDAP3Login in  `'config.py'` and than run the `'__init__.py'`

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)              # Setup a Flask-Login Manager
ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager(app)          # Setup a LDAP3 Login Manager

from app import routes
```

than I got the following exception:

> Exception: Missing user_loader or request_loader. Refer to
> http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/#how-it-works for more info.

than I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61554396/5791355), but using this decorator `@login_manager.user_loader` is probably not enough, is not it?

My assumption is to create a decorator, similar to [this one](https://courses.prettyprinted.com/blog/9788/http-authentication-flask-app) that will allow/forbid an access to a user:

```py
import getpass
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
from functools import wraps 

def auth_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        current_user = getpass.getuser() # current_user will be later acquired via Kerberos
        auth = ldap_manager.get_user_info_for_username(current_user)
        if auth:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
   
        return make_response('Could not verify your login!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="You are not our user!"'})

    return decorated
```

Also, I cannot find a similar or even related thread e.g.

- [github/flask-ldap3-login/flask_ldap3_login/forms.py](https://github.com/nickw444/flask-ldap3-login/blob/master/flask_ldap3_login/forms.py)
- [Authenticate with Flask-LDAP3-Login based on group membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342486/flask-ldap3-login-how-to-authenticate-based-on-group-membership)
- [Flask Authentication With LDAP](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/flask-authentication-with-ldap--cms-23101)
- [Integrate LDAP Authentication with Flask](https://soshace.com/integrate-ldap-authentication-with-flask/)
- [The Flask Mega-Tutorial Part V: User Logins](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins)

Comment: If you're saying the middleware will handle Kerberos, it feels like really isn't your app's job to be sending WWW-Authenticate -- it's the middleware's job. (And after all, the user _has_ authenticated successfully via  Kerberos at this point. If they're not _authorized_ that's a 403.)